# Including content from legacy app: via plugin or custom content?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, api

I am looking to integrate content that exist in a legacy system to a wordpress blog. The content can be accessed from the legacy system via SOAP.

I have some PHP experience and some (limited) experience with Wordpress so I would like to ask  what the best approach for something like this would be.

In terms of how I need it to work there are three elements. One is that the content items would be displayed in a list, second is that more detail of each item could appear on it's own page and third is that there would be a specific form (which will need to eventually send some  stuff back via SOAP) for each item (and detail page).

At first I thought that I should create and use a plugin (or an existing one but I can't find a generic SOAP one) but I read a bit about custom post types and I wonder if maybe that's what I should use. The problem is that the content will be changing in the legacy system and this site needs to only have the current content so I guess plugin is maybe the only way.

I just don't feel comfortable enough with my wordpress experience to feel I am going to make the best choice here. In terms of responses I would be willing to consider other options I haven't covered (because I just don't know what they would be) but otherwise some advice on direction here would be really appreciated. If this is too vague I would be happy to supply more info on any specific points.

Comment: Does the so called " legacy system" have a DB with some clear division ? if the site needs to have ONLY The current content of your system, you can simply take the information from the DB and import it into the relevant ones in WP . SOAP is great , but can complicate things. I once had configured a system that took data from an ever-changing server with SOAP and put it in wordpress. but the DB synch can be in some cases a pain. if you do not need ON-LINE LIVE updates, so soap IMHO is not necessary.

Comment: The legacy system has a db and it's fairly well structured but the problem is that beyond being on another server there are updates that would need to be reflected, if not in real time then close to. So I could write a tool I suppose to do this but it seemed like a "hack-y" approach to me but maybe it really is the best way. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

well - I somehow understood that you need only the CURRENT state . anyhow, what I proposed can be done also with soap, but IMHO - it is easier with with direct Sql query, and then parse that query and put it inside the correspondent wp table . you can use cron to give it timing intervals.